# detect if wlan is turned off

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, .net-4.5, wifi

can anybody give me a hint, how to programmatically detect in C# on Windows Phone **8.1.** App (not 8.0!), if the WLAN is enabled / disabled?
I don't want to change these settings, just need to know...

The Solution is a Windows 8.1 universal app, and the (Windows Phone 8.1) project just references 
*.Net for Windows Store Apps* and *Windows Phone 8.1*.
Adding the *C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Phone.dll* as suggested and querying the **IsWiFiEnabled** property does not work
- Compiler error: Cannot find type System.SystemException in mscorlib.dll

Thanks,
Marher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a Non 8.1 Silverlight solution:

You can use the `Windows.Networking.Connectivity` namespace to query this.

[MSDN NetworkInformation class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.aspx)

An example to get you started

```
bool is_wifi_enabled = false;
Guid adapter_id = new Guid();

// get the list of connection profiles
// we need the adpater id for the wifi
foreach (var item in NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles())
{

    // check if wifi
    if (item.IsWlanConnectionProfile)
    {
        // tag the adapter
        adapter_id = item.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId;
    }
}

// get all lan adapters (this most likely will be empty if wlan is disabled)
foreach (var item in NetworkInformation.GetLanIdentifiers())
{
    if (item.NetworkAdapterId == adapter_id)
    {
        is_wifi_enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I dont want to add Silverlight - I just want to work with Phone 8.1. SDK

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot. @MS: where is IsWiFiEnabled gone?

Comment: @xy np, if it solved your problem - please marked it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `IsWiFiEnabled` property of [DeviceNetworkInformation class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can refer to the [How-To network information page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202859(v=vs.105).aspx) if you need other network informations.

Regards.

Comment: Nope, if I add Microsoft.Phone.dll (C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\Microsoft.Phone.dll) to my Windows Phone 8.1 project, and querying IsWiFiEnabled, I get an compiler error: Cannot find System.SystemException in module mscorlib.dll

Comment: @xy That seems unrelated to querying `IsWiFiEnabled`. If it were missing, you'd get something like `Cannot find DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled`. Can you produce a [mcve] for it? (I realize it's unlikely after two years, but this has gotten me curious)