# How to check if wifi is turned on/off in platform Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

The method DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled ins't available on WP8.1 any suggestion for check wifi is turned on/off?

I should get only if the wifi is turned on/off in platform.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I tried it, but according to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation.iswifienabled(v=vs.105).aspx), `DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled` should be available for:

> **Windows Phone OS**
>   Supported in: 8.1, 8.0, 7.1

If ti is not then you should probably fill in the bug report to Microsoft.

Comment: It is available only Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight, but my project is non Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Using WinRT API GetHostNames() which returns list of the local host names(ipaddress) on the device. Based on Iana interface, you can identify whether it’s Cellular or Wifi. If the IP address is available for WiFi , then you can assume that it is enabled.

Comment: Thank you, but if wifi enabled without network connected? With this not return wifi IP address, then wifi is disabled, but wifi is enabled.

Comment: I rephrased the question. can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use getconnectionProfiles.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getconnectionprofiles

Answer (score 0):

See my workaround here [WiFi enable/disabled based on ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754865/detect-if-wlan-is-turned-off/26756021#26756021).

It involves matching the WiFi NetworkAdapterId with all IDs that are turned on.

Comment: Thank you, but if wifi enabled without network connected? With this not return the lan adapters, then wifi is "disabled", but wifi is enabled. I should get only if the wifi is on/off in platform.

Comment: I rephrased the question. can you help me?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you're connected to a network.  If wifi is on it will be one of the ids in the list.   The trick is to find which one it is,

Comment: I did a test with wifi ON, but no network connected. With this the method return `false`, but should return `true`. right?

Comment: the solution that I need, is the same `Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled` used in Silverlight project. When the wifi is OFF the property return `false` and when the wifi is ON, connected or not the network the property return `true`.