# Check if WLAN or LAN is disabled

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

A user can manually disable LAN or WLAN from the Control Panel. How can I check if the WLAN or LAN is disabled or not in UWP? I tried with device information class, where I am unable to find a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [detect if wlan is turned off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754865/detect-if-wlan-is-turned-off)

Comment: I don't want to find WIFI is off or on.User can manually enable or disabled the adapter in the control panel under network adapter settings. I want to find weather it is enabled or disabled

Comment: How does the accepted answer on that question not answer your problem?

Comment: In that thread they were discussing about weather WLAN is on or off, but in my case i want to find the Network card is enabled or disabled

Comment: That's the bit where it enumerates `NetworkInformation.GetLanIdentifiers()`

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the `Windows.Networking.Connectivity` namespace (from Windows Runtime API) to query the status of this.

You can use `GetConnectProfiles()` to acquire the list of profiles for connections, active or otherwise, on the local machine.

For more details, please check **[NetworkInformation class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.aspx)**.

Additionally, here's an example you can refer to in **[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754865/detect-if-wlan-is-turned-off)**.

Comment: User can manually disable the LAN or WLAN from the control panel. if i am unable to access network, i want to check weather that is disabled or not.Is is achievable in UWP?

Comment: Then you can use `WiFiAdapter.ScanAsync` to request for a list of networks scanned by your adapter. You could find the method under the [WiFiAdapter class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).